# Divide linked-list into 2 sublists with equal sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, pseudocode, partition-problem

I'm trying to divide a linked-list into 2 sublists with equal sum. These sublists do not need to consist of consecutive elements.

I have a linked list as

```
Eg.1
LinkedList={1,7,5,5,4}
should be divided into
LinkedList1={1,5,5}
LinkedList2={7,4}
```

Both have the same sum of elements as 11.

```
Eg.2
LinkedList={42,2,3,2,2,2,5,20,2,20}
This should be divided into two list of equal sum i.e 50.
LinkedList1={42,3,5}
LinkedList2={2,2,2,2,20,2,20}
```

Can someone provide some pseudocode to solve this problem?

This is what I've thought so far:

1. Sum the elements of linked list and divide by 2.
2. Now till the sum of your linkedlist1 is less than the sum of linkedlist/2 keep pushing elements into linkedlist1.
3. If not equal and less than linkedlist sum/2 move to the next element and the current element can be pushed to the linkedlist2.

But this would only work if the elements are in a particular order.

Comment: Am sure the one who downvoted neither have a answer for this nor a reason for downvote.

Comment: a reason for downvoting may be that you didn't show what you have done so far...

Comment: haha cool..What i have done so far? do you want me to post the code for dividing a linklist into two sublist? whihc have elements in increasing order?that would be totally irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, post your _attempt_ to divide the list. The sorting makes searching easier (faster).

Comment: May be you want to LEARN. Here it is: Simply add the elements of the linklist. `1)Sum the elements of linked list and divide by 2. 2)Now till the sum of your linkedlist1 is less than the sum of linkedlist/2 keep pushing elements into linkedlist1.This would only work if the elements are in a particular order. 3)If not equal and less than linkedlist sum/2 move to the next element and the current element can be pushed to the linkedlist2.`

Comment: @alian:::::::::`Seems someone vanished with his Super Techie PsuedoCode and deleted it instantly because he himself was not getting it.
Rather than providing the solution you are concentration on giving explanations about downvote.
Anyways lets not stretch further.Please comment only if you have a solution.Lets not waste others time.`

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [the partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

There are a few approaches to solving the problem, but I'll just mention the most common 2 below (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) for more details on either approach or other approaches).

---

This can be solved with a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach, which basically comes down to, for each element and value, either including or excluding that element, and looking up whether there's a subset summing to the corresponding value. More specifically, we have the following recurrence relation:

> `p(i, j)` is `True` if a subset of `{ x1, ..., xj }` sums to `i` and `False` otherwise.
>
> `p(i, j)` is `True` if either `p(i, j − 1)` is `True` or if `p(i − xj, j − 1)` is `True`
> `p(i, j)` is `False` otherwise

Then `p(N/2, n)` tells us whether a subset exists.

The running time is `O(Nn)` where `n` is the number of elements in the input set and `N` is the sum of elements in the input set.

---

The "approximate" greedy approach (doesn't necessarily find an equal-sum partition) is pretty straight-forward - it just involves putting each element in the set with the smallest sum. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
INPUT:  A list of integers S
OUTPUT: An attempt at a partition of  S into two sets of equal sum
1  function find_partition( S ):
2     A ← {}
3     B ← {}
4     sort  S in descending order
5     for i in S:
6        if sum(A) <= sum(B)
7           add element i to set A
8        else
9           add element i to set B
10    return {A, B}
```

The running time is `O(n log n)`.